# Swift delegate & optional

Tags: ios, delegates, swift, option-type

I've declared this protocol

```
protocol ReactorDelegate {
  func ReactorUpdateUI()
}
```

In my Model I have a delegate optional property and checking if isn't nill, unwrap it to call the protocol methode provided by the VC.

```
var delegate:ReactorDelegate? 

if delegate {delegate?.ReactorUpdateUI()}
```

My VC follows the protocol and has the ReactorUpdateUI methode

```
class VC_Reactor: UIViewController, ReactorDelegate
```

I'm trying to create an instance of the Model in the VC but this fails

```
let reactorCore=Reactor()
```

**ERROR: 'Reactor' is not constructible with '()'**  what let's me know that not all properties have an initial value.

I can work-around it by making my delegate in the VC an implicitly unwrapped optional 
`var reactorCore:Reactor!` 
and in the ViewDidLoad with a custom init: `reactorCore=Reactor(delegate:self)`

I don't understand why I need a custom `init(delegate:ReactorDelegate)` if I declare the delegate property optional.

Comment: maybe you need to implement initWithNibName:bundle:

Comment: and what is `Reactor` anyway? a class, a struct, a protocol? or what? you have forgot to define it entirely. who can even give you any answer if you have not shared every info with us?

Comment: It's the first time I post a question and I tryed to be complete, fail. Reactor is a class in my Model.

Comment: What is the class parent of Reactor?

Answer (score 18):

You need to mark the method as optional in your delegate protocol:

```
@objc protocol ReactorDelegate {
    optional func ReactorUpdateUI()
}
```

Then mark your class as `@objc` and use optional chaining on the method, too:

```
delegate?.ReactorUpdateUI?()
```

*Note:* When writing a protocol, it's easiest to keep everything required and stub out the methods in your class, then when everything works go back and make what you want optional be optional. The error messages you get are pretty opaque, so this way you're working with fewer issues at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your protocol like this:

```
protocol ReactorDelegate: class {
   func ReactorUpdateUI()
}
```

And after, your delegate:

```
weak var delegate: ReactorDelegate
delegate?.ReactorUpdateUI()
```